# Ubuntu 16.04 will not play audio

Tags: 16.04, sound, alsa, 16.10

It clearly detects my sound card, as well as plugging my headphones in and out of the front panel. (The Sound Settings shows the headphones when they're plugged in., and removes the option when they're unplugged.) But no audio plays. I've also noticed that the muted audio notification shows up occasionally as the system starts up, even though the actual volume icon isn't muted.

So far i've tried.

- Upgrading to 16.10
- Connecting the headphones to the optical and line-in ports on the back of the PC.
- Setting Windows 7's audio (My PC is dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu.) to 100% before booting into Ubuntu.
- Installing pavucontrol and trying every built-in audio profile.
- everything on this article: https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/ reinstalling alsa and Pulse required me to reinstall ubuntu-desktop. and the "speech-dispatcher run=" option was already set to "no".

Here's what aplay -l is giving me.

```
    **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CA0132 Analog [CA0132 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: CA0132 Digital [CA0132 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

and here's what "lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"" is giving me.

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 132
    Memory at da140000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at da120000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

--
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GP104 High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at dc080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
```

It clearly seems to recognize the sound card in question (a Creative Sound Core 3D, which is a component in the GA-Z170X-Gaming 7 motherboard i'm using.) Yet it can't play audio off it.